# Groovy: How do I sort an ArrayList of String:s in length-of-string order?

Tags: string, sorting, groovy, arraylist

How do I sort an `ArrayList` of `String`'s in length-of-string order in Groovy?

Code:

```
def words = ['groovy', 'is', 'cool']
// your code goes here:
// code that sorts words in ascending length-of-word order
assert words == ['is', 'cool', 'groovy']
```

There are certainly more than one way to do it - so I'll grant the answer to the person who provides the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
words = words.sort { it.size() }
```

To get descending order

```
words = words.sort { -it.size() }
```

Comment: it's a shame that this is - even in 2013 - not part of the official groovy docs (at least i have never found this).

Comment: @Panique: what exactly would you expect to find? The sort method is in the API docs, the rest is just understanding how closures work.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt I just searched for hours, days, weeks, years and maybe centuries for that little minus in `-it.size()`. Never seen that before. A good documentation should give such information, as this is basic stuff.

Comment: Thanks ! ascending works, however, the descending order with `-` does not

Answer (score 0):

If in the accepted solution `{ -it.size() }` doesn't work for descending order, you could try this:
`{ -1 * it.size() }`

Comment: How are those things different?